# Should I use SQL to save time? and How?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, site-maintenance

I created some landing page template in which I test various products.

currently it is a .php file which I manually change each time, along with 3 other files, plus an image, and then upload all of them to my ftp, and edit the .htaccess file to make the links "pretty".

It is pretty inefficient, as it wastes too much time and I guess there's a way to automate this.

basically I need a way just to update the product's price, product name, product image, products description, page title; update links in the related other 3 files; and update the .htaccess file according to the cannonical url which I choose on the product page.

Someone told me that I can use SQL in order to achieve that, is that correct?
I have zero knowledge in SQL. he told me I can either used some designated system to update these files, or rather use something called DB.

Is this the way to go? should I try to learn it myself? from where?
or where and for how much can I hire someone to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Just to balance the equation, since there is already an answer suggesting a SQL database... as John suggests this is a matter of opinion and depends on your situation. It sounds as if you have a _small finite amount of information_ that needs to change, by just one person. I would perhaps consider simply using a PHP include (possibly an assoc array) that contains this information, rather than a SQL database (the assoc array is the "database"). A SQL database won't necessarily be quicker or easier to update and it won't instantly fix having to update .htaccess and the uploading of images.

Comment: Ok, I'm really confused now and don't know from where to start. I don't even know what to google about. every google result dive into technical details while I don't even know what I need exactly.  What I imagine is to have some excel sheet, to which everytime I Can add a new line, with another product name, price, htaccess value,image src, etc, and it would generate a new file instantly. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the site.

This is exactly what SQL is for, and if you're already using php you are half way there. You should be able to look up how to access values from a MySQL database from php, and how to change them from the command line, and have the system up and running in under an hour.

The best way to do this would be to make one row for each page with the content you need. Then you can either use php my admin or the command line to change those values whenever necessary.